# How to catch null reference exception to create a dump?

Tags: c#

Application is not getting crashed while trying for null reference exception. Code is as below.

```
string a = null;   // These two lines are in another method.
int i = a.Length; // These two lines are used to raise null reference exception.
```

In main()

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
currentDomain.UnhandledException += AppDomain_UnhandledException;
Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
```

AppDomain_UnhandledException is never reached. and Application_ThreadException is also never reached. Is there any other option to catch this.

Comment: Is this a console application? wpf? windows forms?

Comment: Is the `a.Length` actually executed?  Is there a try/catch surrounding it?

Comment: Right now experimenting with that - really interesting question. Am I far off in thinking you want to load untrusted plugins in a secondary AppDomain for your App?

Comment: are you handling exception somewhere in between? why not in main use throw new Exception() and see if it works

Comment: You must be catching the exception somewhere. I can't reproduce.

Comment: This is a windows form, and exception is not handled using try catch.

Comment: In Visual Studio, go to Menu -> Debug -> Exceptions... and check "User-unhandled" for CLR exceptions. The debugger will stop the execution of your code when an exception in thrown, even if it's caught, so you'll be able using step-by-step debug to know **where** your exception is caught (I'm pretty sure it is).

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2010 does not show unhandled exception message in a 64-bit WinForms Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-64-bit-winforms-applicatio)